# Stormpath information for login

Tags: node.js, api, express, stormpath

I've been trying to find needed info to get my stormpath api to work so i would have a very basic login funtion to access my app, i've gotten it to work once before in another project but the problem is, i cant seem to find any of the needed information.

I Log into the Stormpath site and there is hundreds of tabs and pages and i need to find

export STORMPATH_CLIENT_APIKEY_ID=

export STORMPATH_CLIENT_APIKEY_SECRET=

export STORMPATH_APPLICATION_HREF=

to get the app working, or so i assume.
Can anyone point out where i can get all the needed infos for this api to work?

There is no existing key-pair or anything for this project yet.
Or there is one i think they call them "applications"
but i have no idea where to get info or keys for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you first log in and land on the Home tab, click the Manage API Keys button on the right hand side:

[image: Manage API Keys]

This will let you generate an API Key/Secret pair, which will be downloaded as a file. Open that file up to get the values you need to set as environment variables.

If you haven't already created an Application resource to represent your application, switch to the Applications tab and click Create Application. Once you've created one, you can copy the href from the details page, above the ID field.

Be aware that the [Stormpath API is shutting down](https://stormpath.com/oktaplusstormpath) in August 2017.

Comment: Thank you! Can you recommend some other such service for node? All i need for this is a simple login, but for future it might be good to get some experience with some such system.